# USB Descriptor: iInterface and iFunction - is there a point?

Tags: usb

In a USB Configuration Descriptor you have the option of providing `iFunction` and `iInterface` string descriptor indexes to Function Descriptors and Interface Descriptors respectively.

Is there any point to implementing these descriptors? Adding them, I can see the strings I assign in `lsusb -v -d vid:pid` for the device, but that is the only place I seem to be able to see them at the moment.

Are these string descriptors used anywhere else? Maybe in another operating system?

Yes, I guess I could get at them with `libusb` in my own software, but that's besides the point - I'm looking at the OS level - is there anything (besides the odd diagnostic tool) that would make use of them?

BTW: this is for a composite device with a number of interfaces of different types.

Comment: Maybe this links help: https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9667981/

Comment: they show up deep in control panels, and if famous, other devices might consider them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [link](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9667981/)

Permits distinguishing between two /dev/videoX entries from the same
physical UVC device (that naturally share the same iProduct name).

This change matches current Windows behavior by prioritizing iFunction
over iInterface, but unlike Windows it displays both iProduct and
iFunction/iInterface strings when both are available.

Comment: So not really any use for anything else then yet? Only UVC? That's great, I'll leave them out of my USB stack then. No point in wasting space...

Comment: It seems so, to be honest, I never programmed for something specifically for USB.

Answer (score 1):

In USB, all string descriptors are optional, see Section

> 9.6.7 String
>
> String descriptors are optional. As noted previously, if a device does not
> support string descriptors, all references to string
> descriptors within device, configuration, and interface descriptors
> must be reset to zero

If your device doesn't have specific need to discriminate between some modes, you can skip them.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I am asking if there's any real benefit to implementing them.